# /var and /usr eating up space- low on disk space - What do I delete?

Tags: disk-usage

I know what's taking up space by utilizing the disk usage command.

The directory `/var` takes up 11 GB and its sub-directory `var/lib` takes up 8 GB.
And `/usr` directory takes up 2 GB.

5xx MB is remaining out of my 20 GB root disk and I don't have a lot of applications installed.

How do I figure out what do I delete so that it does not break my system?

**UPDATE**: After taking a detailed look, I found that the culprit is `/var/lib/flatpak` I've utilized Flatpak to install the applications, but I don't have anything that big of an application to take up so much space. Here's the screenshot of what's taking how much inside `flatpak`:

```
~$ du -sh /var/lib/flatpak/* | sort -n
1.1G   /var/lib/flatpak/app
2.3G   /var/lib/flatpak/runtime
4.1G   /var/lib/flatpak/repo
14M    /var/lib/flatpak/appstream
412K   /var/lib/flatpak/exports
```

Is there a way I can force Flatpak to reside in the home directory instead while not re-installing the apps?

Comment: Take a look in `/var/log` first, maybe you have many large logfiles.

Comment: UPDATE: After taking a detailed look, I found that the culprit is /var/lib/flatpak

I've utilized flatpack to install the applications, but I don't have anything that big of an application to take up so much space :/ 

Here's the screenshot of what's taking how much inside flatpak: http://i.imgur.com/57e2mUm.png

Is there a way I can force flatpak to reside in the home directory instead by not re-installing the apps?

Comment: Move the folder and replace it by a symbolic link to the new location.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for suggesting the workaround. Will do.

Comment: Hello. Please don't use screenshots for text in your question. Instead, copy from the terminal, paste into your question, select what you just pasted with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor to format it correctly.

Comment: Sidenote: When using `du -sh` you can/should also use `sort -h` (instead of `sort -n`). It sorts by human readable units and is aware that 4GB > 8 MB while `-n` is not.

Comment: You need a larger hard disk, or Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 3):

The `flatpak uninstall --unused` command removes runtimes that are no longer needed.

Comment: +1 This freed up 3GB on my disk.